# Installing Tails on Ubuntu and get a disk error

Tags: usb, software-installation

I've been searching for hours and can't find an answer to this.

I open Tails installer through the application finder, click install and select "tails-i386-2.11.iso".  I then click the USB that I am using SanDisk Ultra Fit (124.2 GB) - /dev/sda.  I click Install Tails and I receive this error:

```
tails-i386-2.11.iso selected
Unmounting mounted filesystems on '/dev/sda'
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.NotAuthorized: Not authorized to perform operation
Tails installation failed!
udisks-error-quark: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.NotAuthorized: Not authorized to perform operation (3)
```

I have `sudo -s` enabled, and I have tried GNOME and it still will not load it up.

Comment: Apparently you're trying to install in the same driver you're booting from. AskUbuntu supports Ubuntu and official derivatives only. Tails is not Ubuntu. You may get further help at http://unix.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: Are you using the tails installer? Can you burn a disc from the iso? Best I can suggest is to to tails.boum.org & read the install